# How can I plot a hexagon inside this cylinder so that it is always in the same direction as the cylinder, no matter what the orientation is?

Tags: webmathematica, mathematica-online

How can I plot a hexagon inside this cylinder so that it is always in the same direction as the cylinder, no matter what the orientation is? In addition, the hexagon must always be the same size as the cylinder.

For example, start at the origin (10,9,8) and go to (1,2,3)?

```
Graphics3D [{Cylinder [{{10, 9, 8}, {1, 2, 3}}, 0.5]}
```

I tried this:

```
Table [Show [Graphics3D [Cylinder [{{0., 0., 0}, {0., 0., l}}, 1]], PolyhedronData [{"Prism", 6}]], {l, 0.1 , 3, 0.1}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{v1, v2} = {{10, 9, 8}, {1, 2, 3}};
r = .5;
n = 6;
reg = Cylinder[{v1, v2}, r];
{e1, e2} = Most@Normal@Orthogonalize[HodgeDual[v2 - v1]];
pts = Table[
   v1 + r*Cos[2 k*π/n]*e1 + r*Sin[2 k*π/n]*e2, {k, 1, n}];
tranpts = TranslationTransform[v2 - v1] /@ pts;
top = Polygon[pts];
bottom = Polygon[tranpts];
surfaces = 
  MapThread[
   Polygon@*Join, {Partition[pts, 2, 1, 1], 
    Reverse[Partition[tranpts, 2, 1, 1], {2}]}];
Graphics3D[{{Cyan, top, bottom}, 
  Riffle[ColorData["Atoms"] /@ Range[n], surfaces]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Method` option to get an n-gonal prism inscribed in a clylinder in two ways:

1. Use the `Method` suboption `"CylinderPoints" -> n`, or
2. Use `Tube` instead of `Cylinder` with the `Method` suboption `"TubePoints" -> n`

```
Row[{Graphics3D[{ Opacity[.5, Blue],Cylinder[{{10, 9, 8}, {1, 2, 3}}, 2]}, 
    ImageSize -> 300],
  Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5, Red], Cylinder[{{10, 9, 8}, {1, 2, 3}}, 2]},
    Method -> {"CylinderPoints" -> 6}, ImageSize -> 300],
  Graphics3D[{ CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[.5, Green], Tube[{{10, 9, 8}, {1, 2, 3}}, 2]},
    Method -> {"TubePoints" -> 6}, ImageSize -> 300]}]
```

[image]

With the second method we can have cylinders and inscribed prisms in the same graphics (We cannot do this with the first method since the option `"CylinderPoints" -> n` applies to all `Cylinder` objects):

```
Graphics3D[{ Opacity[.4, Blue],
  Cylinder[{{10, 9, 8}, {1, 2, 3}}, 2], 
  CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[.5, Red],
  Tube[{{10, 9, 8}, {1, 2, 3}}, 2]},
  Method -> {"TubePoints" -> 4}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]